# How do i navigate with webbrowser each time to one html page?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 44 html addresses and i want each time to navigate to one html address.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 45; i++)
            {
                adrBarTextBox.Text = sourceUrl + i;
                getCurrentBrowser().Navigate(adrBarTextBox.Text);
            }
```

In the webbrowser document completed event i need that only when it finished to navigate and loading all the page including javascript and everything only then to navigate to the next html address.

```
private void Form1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          // If page loaded completly then do something
        }
```

The problems are that the loop will try to navigate each time a new page html before the last one loaded and before i did with it something in the completed event.

EDIT

Button click event:

```
private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetHtmls();
            CheckQueue();
        }
```

Then the GetHtmls method:

```
private Queue<Uri> myUrls = new Queue<Uri>();
        private bool isBusy = false;

        private void GetHtmls()
        {   
            for (int i = 1; i < 45; i++)
            {
                adrBarTextBox.Text = sourceUrl + i;
                targetHtmls = (combinedHtmlsDir + "\\Html" + i + ".txt");
                Uri targetUri = new Uri(sourceUrl + i);
                myUrls.Enqueue(targetUri);
            }
        }
```

Then the checkQueue method:

```
private void CheckQueue()
        {
            if (isBusy)
                return; // We're downloading some page right now, don't disturb

            isBusy = true; // OK, let's get started

            if (myUrls.Count == 0) // No more pages to download, we're done
            {
                isBusy = false;
                return;
            }

            Uri uri = myUrls.Dequeue(); // Get one URL from queue
            getCurrentBrowser().Navigate(uri);
        }
```

And last the completed event:

```
private void Form1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            myUrls.Dequeue();
            // If page loaded completly then do something

            isBusy = false; // We're done
            CheckQueue(); // Check next page in queue
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're navigating to all pages at the same time I the loop. In my opinion you need a queue which will be checked when one page is downloaded.

```
private Queue<Uri> myUrls = new Queue<Uri>();
private bool isBusy = false;
```

The `isBusy` flag will be for our next method, because we want to download only one page at once.

```
private void CheckQueue()
{
    if (isBusy)
        return; // We're downloading some page right now, don't disturb

    isBusy = true; // OK, let's get started

    if (myUrls.Count == 0) // No more pages to download, we're done
    {
        isBusy = false;
        return;
    }

    Uri uri = myUrls.Dequeue(); // Get one URL from queue
    webBrowser.Navigate(uri); // Download the page
}
```

We will be calling this method when one page will be downloaded.

```
private void Form1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // If page loaded completly then do something

    isBusy = false; // We're done
    CheckQueue(); // Check next page in queue
}
```

And of course you have to call `CheckQueue()` to initialize the process of downloading pages.

Comment: Lukasz im getting error on this line on the right side: Uri uri = myUrls.Dequeue(); Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Uri'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I guess you forgot '<Uri>' in queue declaration

Comment: Lukasz i tried it and what i see is that when its navigate i don't see that the page is completly loaded then its going to the completed event doing the checkQueue() again and the next uri is 3 i mean first uri is 1 then 3 then 7 then 9. another thing is where do i add/make the part of getting the source code like view-source content from each uri and write it to a text file ?

Comment: Lukasz please look at my question i added the code after changed it according to your solution added it to the bottom of my question.

Comment: You're doing myUrls.Dequeue(); twice, so you're skipping some pages. Remove myUrls.Dequeue();  from Form1_DocumentCompleted

Comment: And you can get the source code of the pege where you have this comment: // If page loaded completly then do something

Answer (score 0):

You can use  *[TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)* + *[async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx)* for this

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = null;
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    tcs.TrySetResult(null);
};

for (int i = 1; i < 45; i++)
{
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    webBrowser1.Navigate(sourceUrl + i);
    await tcs.Task;
    //... Navigation completed ...
}
```

PS: Don't forget to mark your method *async*